# Replacing incorrect names with the right names using python similarity match

Tags: python, function, matcher

I need to replace some names of the countries with the correct name.below is my dataframe

```
names   country
0   1   Austria
1   2   Autrisa
2   3   Egnald
3   4   Sweden
4   5   Swweden
5   6   India
```

I need to replace the above countries with the right names.Below is the output i need

```
names   country
0   1   Austria
1   2   Austria
2   3   England
3   4   Sweden
4   5   Sweden
5   6   India
```

```
correct_names = {'Austria','England','Sweden'}
```

```
def get_most_similar(word, wordlist):
    top_similarity = 0.0
    most_similar_word = word  
    for candidate in wordlist:
        similarity = SequenceMatcher(None, word, candidate).ratio()
        if similarity > top_similarity:
            top_similarity = similarity
            most_similar_word = candidate
            # print(most_similar_word)

    return most_similar_word

data['country'].apply(lambda x: get_most_similar(x,correct_names))
```

The output i am getting is below:-

```
0    Austria
1    Austria
2    England
3     Sweden
4     Sweden
5    England  -- this should be India but it got converted to England
```

Needed help to fix this.

Comment: You told it to pick the closest word from the set  'Austria', 'England' and "Sweden'.  Those are the only names it will ever assign.  Perhaps you want to put a limit on the acceptable similarity.

Comment: How to change the code so that it reads appropriate names..I tried to change the top_similarity to 50.0 but still its not able to capture correctly.

Comment: what is wordlist in your funstion? is it the same as `correct_names` ?

Comment: Maybe 50 is not high enough.  Did you print the similarity values in your false positive?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour yes

Comment: @TimRoberts how can we do that..can you help me out

Comment: ???  Don't you see that you have a variable called `similarity`?  If you print that along with the word that generated it, it will show you how close you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

You assigned

```
correct_names = {'Austria', 'England', 'Sweden'}
```

But this is not appropriate for the current use case,
as India can be a correct name but it does appear in that `set`.

You want to assign

```
correct_names = {'Austria', 'England', 'India', 'Sweden'}
```

Comment: The issue is if there are more countries i.e. more than 50 so I need to give names in the country_names. Is that something better I can do

Comment: It's not like the ISO committee keeps the list of country names secret or anything. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2

Comment: I understand this..however, is it possible we can put an "if-else" statement so that if the country is present in "correct_names" it will change the name and if not then the country name will be as it is.

Comment: You meant that the other way around.  If it's in `correct_names`, you keep it.  Otherwise, you search.

Comment: yes @TimRoberts